# Cloud IDE for java?

Tags: java, ide, cloud, bitcoin

I’m currently developing code meant to interact with the API of the Bitcoin exchange with an algorithm deciding whether to buy or sell and all. However, I can’t have my laptop running 24/7, so I was wondering, if there exist another option, like some sort of online/cloud IDE for java, which had a workspace to handle files, and could run my program for me - possibly for a small fee? Thank you :)

Comment: why do you want an online IDE? Once your program is compiled you don't need the ide any more, just a place to run it, like Amazon EC2 for example...

Comment: Sorry, still a bit new at this. I guess that maybe was, what I was looking for. I’ll look into it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is **How to Deploy a Java Applet**. Here is a nice tutorial.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html

If you want your applet to be available from anywhere, you will have to embed it on a page that is hosted on the *Internet*. Getting a page hosted costs money, especially if you don't host it yourself, but there are thousands of well-known companies that provide this service. I can't provide any advice on which one is best, for fear of being swallowed alive by StackOverflow.

Once you have a page hosted, you can embed your Java Applet by following this tutorial.

http://www.echoecho.com/applets01.htm

Comment: Sounds about right. Thank you very much! I'll take a look :)

Comment: @user3163020 No problem. If that answered your question, click the green check mark. Also, welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: @John I don't think an applet is required - it seems that the op just needs a plain Java program and a place to run it...

Comment: @assylias You are absolutely correct. No applet required. This is only one solution to a very broad question.

Comment: @assylias I think you're right. Just need a place online to run my code 24/7 without me having to have my laptop on (if that's possible). Oh, and it also have to of course accept some additional class-files attached to  my program - so I guess it sorta have a workspace? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user3163020 Amazon EC2 has free instances so you can try - you can have a full Linux environment there. Compile your program, copy it to the EC2 instance, install java on EC2, and run your program...